# Android: Weird issue in stopping a service

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have an activity that starts a service like that:

```
    Intent youtubeIntent = new Intent(this, YoutubeFeedService.class);
    service = startService(youtubeIntent);
```

and to detect when the service stops I use a broadcast receiver:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    IntentFilter filter; 
    filter = new IntentFilter(YoutubeFeedService.NEW_VIDEO_CELL); 
    receiver = new FeaturedReceiver(); 
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override public void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(receiver); 
    super.onPause();
}



public class FeaturedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");


        if (title.equals("-1") || title.equals("1")){
            //stopService(new Intent(FeaturedActivity.this, service.getClass()));
            try {
                Class serviceClass = Class.forName(service.getClassName());
                stopService(new Intent(FeaturedActivity.this, serviceClass));
            } 
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}

        }

    }
}
```

I first tried to kill the service with

```
stopService(new Intent(FeaturedActivity.this, service.getClass()));
```

but this didn't work, so instead I used

```
try {
                Class serviceClass = Class.forName(service.getClassName());
                stopService(new Intent(FeaturedActivity.this, serviceClass));
            } 
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}
```

And it did work! Can anyone explain what's the difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stopService(new Intent(FeaturedActivity.this, service.getClass()));
```

In this case, `service` is a `ComponentName`. Hence, `service.getClass()` will return `ComponentName.class`. Your service is `YoutubeFeedService.class`.

```
Class serviceClass = Class.forName(service.getClassName());
stopService(new Intent(FeaturedActivity.this, serviceClass));
```

It would seem simpler to call:

```
stopService(new Intent(FeaturedActivity.this, YoutubeFeedService.class);
```